# Communicate between two same directive having isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am novice to angularjs and i have a custom directive which has an isolated scope. I am having problem communicating between two instance of same directive . 
How can i do that ? Your suggestion is highly appreciated .

```
<div date-control="cal1" ng-model="mydate" calendar-properties="calendarProperties1"></div>
<div date-control="cal2" ng-model="mydate2" calendar-properties="calendarProperties2"></div>
```

What i want to do is open both date-control at once having 'to' and 'from' attribute in calendar properties  using some data sharing or any thing ? you can check this  [plnkr sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp).

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: ... and what you are actually trying to achieve. There are numerous ways to communicate (with `require` or with `scope.broadcast` or via parent-child), and the answer would depend on specifics

Comment: @Vineet I have prepared some snippet for this . you can check this http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp. What i want to do is open both at once using some data sharing or any thing ? can you suggest some idea?

Answer (score 1):

directives are just the result of a function call

```
angular.directive('myDir',function(){
  var common;
  return directiveObject;
});
```

directiveObject being the any of the variantes you use to create your directive.The main thing is that right before returning you can declare common(class if you will) variables and methods that can be checked for changes or invoked so you could do something like

```
app.directive('myDir',function(){
  var bus={
    value1:0
  };

  function increase(){
    bus.value1++;
  }

  return {
     scope:{},
     template:"<div><h1>{{counter}}</h1><button ng-click="increase()">add</button></div>"
     controller:function($scope){
       $scope.bus=bus;
       $scope.increase = increase
       $scope.$watch('bus',function(){
         //something here
       })
     }
  };
});
```

a sample of this can be found here. this can be shaped in many ways
http://plnkr.co/edit/d9dpIYCAjOaOBNjoI80u?p=preview

some other methods can be used like emitting and broadcasting events or even using services,  but i like the simplicity of this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can either store this information directly in a Service, or you can have the directives communicate with each other.  In this case, I'd have them communicate.

One option that would work is to use `.$broadcast` to send a message from the `$rootScope` and then use `.$on` to receive that message.

Example: inside your "From" directive

```
// Once "From" date is selected
$rootScope.$broadcast('from:set', date);
```

Then, inside your "To" directive

```
scope.$on('from:set', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);  // Will log "From" date
});
```

There are a lot of different ways you can do this that will work (e.g. you could put them both on the `$rootScope` or you could have them `.$emit` upward instead of `.$broadcast` downward), so use whatever you feel makes the most sense in your case.

There is a great blog post on the subject here: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: thanks @tyler for your answer . I will try using this way .

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote this, other than to make their own answer higher...

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to share data across different $scope. You will get many suggestions, about storing in $rootScope, $broadcast, but these solutions are not optimal as they do the job but with an overhead.

Create a service, and store the properties "to" and "from" into that service, then inject that service into your directive..

http://plnkr.co/edit/xJrBneiU8RU92czHAZ43?p=preview

```
.service("MyService", function(){
  var from = 'Cal1';
  var to = 'Cal1';
  return {from:from, to:to};
})
.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope, MyService) {


    $scope.calendarProperties1 = {

        format: "yyyy-MM-dd",
        label: "Enter the Date From",
        from: MyService.from,
        opened:false
    }

    $scope.calendarProperties2 = {
        format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
        label: "Enter the Date To",
        to: MyService.to,
        opened: false
    }

})
```

In this example, you will be able to see how we can use Service variables inside directives ... Using this solution will solve your problem

**Edit, I have edited your plunker code, to modify the calendar properties object to use data from the service. Now both calendar properties object will get data from the same service variable.. I hope this might solve your problem

Comment: thank you for your solution . My context is little different . I need to share a specific data or call a specific function from a instance of directive to another instance of same directive .Like in your case `<my-dir>1</my-dir><my-dir>2</my-dir>` . I want to call a function on directive <my-dir>2<my-dir> from directive <my-dir>1<my-dir> . Can you suggest some idea.I kind of stuck in this . This would be a great help.

Comment: yes, keep your specific data or function inside the service, so if you change the data from one directive, the other directive will also be affected. If you could share a basic plunker code of your directives, and point the data, I could help you out even more

Comment: Thank you abib .my sample plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/FDigEjyMYm5SVYnQyZGp. In this sample plunker , i want to open two calendar popup directives "date-control" with the  directive having same 'to' and 'from' attribute properties provided  by model bounded properties 'calendar-properties' in the isolated scope of directive . scope.open() is used to open the calendar popup and calendar-propeties attribute 'opened' is true when calendar popup is true. hope you understand my scenario and provide me some hint to process .

Comment: @adib.mosharrof using `$broadcast`, `$emit`, and `$on` do not store the data in the `$rootScope`.  You can accomplish data storage through a 3rd Service as you mentioned, but that's an extra piece that's unnecessary since the Angular team already built in a system for directly messaging between directives.  Your approach would work but would be more brittle and less interchangeable.

Comment: yes, it does not populate the $rootScope ... sorry about that... but using $broadcast, $mit and $on creates an overhead. If im not wrong, they send out events, which the whole application can listen to.. storing data in $rootScope will make it heavier, and as the application grows, its a good practice to keep the $rootScope light.

Using a service, we can inject the data only where we need it... all directives can use data from the service...

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am just sharing what I learnt..

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all for answering and providing some suggestion.If i want to communicate through one directive with another directive of same type i will retrieve the scope of the directive to call or share/get the data of another directive by using .scope() method . There may be other way but i am just a novice of angular and i am using this way to access the methods and data between directives .

Comment: Is this a solution?  If not, you should mark whatever solution helped you as correct.  That way your question can quickly help others if they come across it.

Comment: @tyler I don't know if this is effective way but it actually solve my problem.

Comment: How are you passing the directives' scopes?  Adding some code will help others.  Note that this is almost certainly not the best way to do it though :)

Comment: I don't know this is hack or something . you can get any element/directive scope by angular.element(element).scope() method .

Comment: Woah, very hacky. Would not recommend!  You are very much in the jQuery mindset, when Angular provides these things in a much simpler way than tunneling through objects.

Comment: I didn't find other way effective in my case when i had to communicate between only two specific instance of same directive .

Comment: This type of use case is exactly why the angular team created a messaging system based on `$broadcast`, `$on`, and `$emit`...

Comment: @tyler how can i communicate between two siblings directive using $emit,$on and $broadcast ? can you show with simple example ? I would be glad to do it in this way .

Comment: I have the code in my answer below.  You can have the directive emit via `$rootScope.$broadcast` and listen via `scope.$on`.  Then every instance of the directive will pick up the message whenever one instance broadcasts.

Comment: @tyler I have created a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gVzO00I8BCLp1ElRJxbc . I tried to implement $broadcast and $on .can you suggest how can i open these two at once ? I need to assign scope.opened variable to true to open the calendar directive .

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want the calendars to do, but here is how you can have them send and receive information http://plnkr.co/edit/IX7oye2ATwPr3bNehBDw?p=preview

Comment: @tyler I want to open two calendars at once if each of them have 'to' and 'from' in their calendarProperties if not open a single calendar on click. I tried using $emit , $broadcast and $on but i wasn't successful .